# What is the deal with the pony in Python community?

Tags: python, django, pony

Pony references are in several places:

- http://www.mail-archive.com/python-dev@python.org/msg44751.html
- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pony/
- http://djangopony.com/

Is there a cultural reference that I am missing? What is the deal with ponies?

Comment: It's amazing that this question is still not closed, while other useful questions with a dozens of upvotes are considered off-topic.

Comment: I wonder why it isn't protected yet.

Comment: Sad, nobody asks after The Testing Goat.

Comment: 10 years since I posted that question. How time flies by!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When you start listing what you want, "I want a fast HTTP parser", "I want ORM that just works", "I want higher order functions", the idea is that while you're wishing for things, you might as well wish for a pony too.  This is probably a reference to a Calvin and Hobbes strip from "Someone under the bed is drooling", in which Susie Derkins says that as long as she's dreaming, she might as well wish for a pony.

[image: Comic strip referenced]

Comment: Of course it's kitsch. Thats the whole point. Python is such a serious language and Django such a serious framework that serious web developers can take themselves serious enough to adopt ponies, pink, rainbows, glitter and love to represent their seriousness. It's AWESOME(tm).

Comment: @wisty: Don't add [not-programming-related] tags. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not

Answer (score 15):

Its a Django unofficial mascot. See [this blog post for an explanation](http://twothirty.am/blog/2009/10/07/blessing-mythical-django-pony/).

Python generally uses Monty Python references (and sometimes snake references, for the misguided).

Comment: I think that, being Monty Python fans, we should better ask for a shrubbery, one that look nice. And not too expensive, also.

Comment: the link is now broken

Answer (score 3):

It's the Django mascot.